# going from array[0] to array[n] in C without typing them all out

Tags: c, arrays

Is there a way to go from array[0] to array[n] in C without typing them all out.like:

```
 if(array[0] to array[n] == '_')
```

thanks for the suggestions guys but i only wanted the code to execute if ALL of the elements in the array were ==95, not if just one of them was.i ended up just typing them all out and using && between them.
Thanks anyway :D

Comment: Have you learned about the `for` loop?

Comment: Don't program anything else until you read a book on C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a `for` loop, you can make a function to encapsulate the behaviour you want of being able to check the array inside in `if` condition:

```
int arrayIsJustUnderscores(char *array, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] != '_')
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

// somewhere else in your code:

if (arrayIsJustUnderscores(array, n))
{
    puts("Array is just underscores...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   if (array[i] == '_') {
       // do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

If you want to test the whole array, you must go through a for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    if (array[i] == '_')
        do_something();
```